# z-index issue in ie 7+ and opera

Tags: browser, html, positioning, z-index

Here is the html:

```
<div id = "parent">
   <div id = "one" ></div>
   <div id = "two" ></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#parent
{
  position:    relative;
}
   #parent > #one
   {
     position:  absolute;
     z-index:   10;
     top:       50px;
     left:      50px;  
     width:     100px;
     height:    100px;
     background:  white;        
   }
   #parent > #two
   {
     position:  absolute;
     z-index:   5;
     top:       50px;
     left:      50px;
     height:    50px;
     width:     50px;
     background: black;
   }
```

The problem in ie7+ and opera is that div "one" is not overlapping div "two", why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using below:

```
<div id = "parent">
   <div class= "one" ></div>
   <div class= "two" ></div>
</div>
css:

#parent
{
  position:    relative;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background: yellow;
}
   #parent  .one
   {
     position:  absolute;
     z-index:   10;
     top:       50px;
     left:      50px;  
     width:     100px;
     height:    100px;
     background:  white;        
   }
   #parent .two
   {
     position:  absolute;
     z-index:   5;
     top:       50px;
     left:      50px;
     height:    50px;
     width:     50px;
     background: black;
   }
```

Hope you will get the clue

Comment: whats chaging the id to class's got to do with anything?

Comment: that worked or not?
if not worked then send the screenshot of its output